# Laravel, Eloquent, array when I need just a value

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

It may be a simple thing, but cant figure it out without making more complicated if/else statement which I believe is not needed.

I need to retrieve name of user with specified id number. But there is a chance, that user with given id doesnt exist.

With such code:
`$author = User::select('name')->where('id', $givenId)->firstOr( function () { return 'Gone'; });`

and it works almost fine, but if user exists, Im getting an array {"name":"User"} as a result. Cant just write `->value('name')` at the end cause when user doesnt exists it gives me an error that I run method value on a null object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just call `value` directly on the Builder to return the value of a single column:

```
User::where('id', $givenId)->value('name') ?? 'Gone';
```

This is assuming users have a name that isn't `null` (or `null` equivalent).

Comment: Thanks. As always Im searching for too complicated solution when it comes that easy when you already see it...

Answer (score 0):

Ternary operators are great for the if else short solutions for variables, And using the optional helper will avoid the not set issues

```
$author = optional(User::select('name')
    ->where('id', $givenId)
    ->firstOrFail())->name ?? 'Gone';
```

Otherwise just using the optional works great. e.g.

```
$author = optional(User::select('name')
    ->where('id', $givenId)
    ->firstOrFail())->name
```

Then in the template

```
@if ($auther)
  {{ $author }}
@endif
```

Comment: ->firstOrFail give an error 404 page what I dont want. If I use just ->first() method, then optional method doesnt work - it needs both arguments - strings, not a null like in this case.